# Python: Splitting lists into multiple lists

Tags: python, python-2.7

In python, Suppose I have a list:

```
instruments = ['apd', 'dd', 'dow', 'ecl']
```

How can I split these lists so that it will create:

```
apd[]
dd[]
dow[]
ecl[]
```

Thanks for the help.

Comment: Why do you want to do this? What's your use case?

Comment: a tonne of people ask this same question but none of them **really** want to do it this way, use a dictionary

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You would do this:

```
dictionaries = {i:[] for i in instruments}
```

and you you would refer to each list this way:

```
dictionaries['apd']
dictionaries['dd']
dictionaries['dow']
dictionaries['ecl']
```

This is considered much better practice than actually having the lists in the current namespace, as it would both be polluting and unpythonic.

mshsayem has the method to place the lists in the current scope, but the question is, what benefits do you get from putting them in your current scope?

Standard use cases:

- you already know the names of the items, and want to refer to them directly by name, i.e. `apd.append`
- you don't know the names yet, but you'll use `eval` or `locals` to get the lists, i.e. `eval('apd').append` or `locals()['apd'].append`

Both can be satisfied using dictionaries:

- `dictionaries['<some name can be set programatically or using a constant>'].append`

Comment: Perfect, much cleaner and easier to use a dictionary. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
instruments = ['apd', 'dd', 'dow', 'ecl']
l_dict = locals()
for i in instruments:
    l_dict[i] = []
```

This will create `apd`,`dd`,`dow`,`ecl` lists in the local scope.
Snakes and Cofee's idea is better though.